# Price simulator in jQuery - Adding values into two vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, simulator

I have a **real-time** price simulator in jQuery, and need to check if any record has an 'adhesion price', to add with the final value, but when I try to use the commented data below (var parent) it always add the value, but doesn't remove if checkbox is unchecked.

The idea is, if the ID is not empty, then its value is the adhesion price, and it should add it into adhesion var. And the 'rel' value has to be added into the 'total' var.

And the problem is that I had to use 'rel' instead of value because the value is going to be saved into a mysql table, for reference. And I used the 'id' for the adhesion value.

HTML checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" rel="20" id="" name="opc[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" rel="10" id="" name="opc[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" rel="30" id="150" name="opc[]" value="3">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var total = 0;
        var adhesion = 0;

        function calcTotal(){
            $("input:checked").each(function(){
                var value = $(this).attr("rel");
                /*var parent      = $(this).id;
                if(parent.value != ""){
                    adhesion += parseFloat(parent);
                }*/
                total += parseFloat(value);
            });
        }

        $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
            if(adhesion != 0){
                total = adhesion;
            }else{
                total = 0;
            }
            calcTotal();
            $(".monthly_val").html("$ "+total.toFixed(2));
        });
    });
```

**Added [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hulimiruci/1/edit?html,js,output) with changes.**

Comment: How are those values being applied to "rel" and "id?" If it is on the server then why couldn't the server determine which value to send back? For instance if the adhesion value is null then obviously the price is the total but if the value is not null then it replaces the value in "rel" that effectively takes away your problem on the client.

Comment: Values are being returned from a mysql table. My problem is that I cannot save the price in the 'value' field, because it's going to be recorded in another table, for reference.

Comment: Forgot to say, but it's a real-time simulator, that's why jQuery :)

Comment: note: numeric ids ar invalid up to HTML 4.01, since html5 these restriction are no longer relevant.
I would recommend to use the data-attributes and jQuery .data()-function for the values

Comment: Hmm of course, my bad. But I still got errors, maybe another method... Anyone knows how to use 'data-...' the right way?

Comment: @DimasPante well HTML5 has the ability to embed custom data attributes which would work in this instance.

Comment: <input data-val1="30" data-val2="150" > as html and .data('val1') in jQuery

Comment: when using the data attributes, don't mix .attr() and .data() for appending and reading values. The two functions won't fit together

Comment: You really should not use Id to store a value, but as a mean to access the element. If you want to add custom data to the field, then use the data- attribute, as shown in a previous comment. data-adhesionPrice="50" for example

Comment: Thanks for all, I created this bin width the changes, but it still returns the same problem as before (try clicking multiple times at price 3): http://jsbin.com/hulimiruci/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around a bit with your code and when I got right this function should behave as you wish:

```
function calcTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    var adh = 0;
        $("input:checked").each(function(){
            var value  = $(this).data("price");
            var parent = $(this).data("adhesion");
            if(parent !== 0){
                adh += parseFloat(parent);
            }
            total += parseFloat(value);
        });
      return total+adh;
    }

    $("input:checkbox").click(function(){
        var endprice = calcTotal();
        $(".v_mensal").html("R$ "+endprice.toFixed(2));
    });
```

I added a return-value to the function and switched the scope of the variables a bit.
I hope this will help you.

**Link to updated [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nucoqukequ/2/edit?html,js,output)**